# Determine the number of $5$ digit numbers in which no digit occurs more than twice (numbers starting with $0$ are allowed).

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Determine the number of $5$ digit numbers in which no digit occurs more than twice (numbers starting with $0$ are allowed).

I see there $3$ possible groups of scenarios:

1. No digits repeat $ = 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$
2. We have one pair of same digits $ = 10 \cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$, because: we choose $1$ of $10$ digits for the pair, then we choose $2$ of $5$ positions in number to put them in (in that same moment we choose the other $3$ in which we place the digits that do not repeat), then we choose the digits for the $3$ places that are left.
3. We have two different pairs of same digits $ = \binom{10}{2} \cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{3}{2} \cdot 8$, because we choose which $2$ of $10$ digits to appear twice, then we choose $2$ of $5$ positions for the smaller of chosen digits, then we choose $2$ of remaining $3$ positions for the larger of selected digits, then we choose $1$ of $8$ remaining digits to fill the remaining one position.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @Karl that would be incorrect... You would have to subtract the cases where 4 numbers recur, 5 numbers recur, etc

Comment: I'm going to nitpick and say  "What's your answer.  You described three scenarios and calculated values for them.  How do you use the scenarios to get an actual answer?"  Now if you had said "and then I add them" I'd say "yes, so for as I can tell in my pre-coffee grog that appears to be a correct way to do it", but you didn't say "and then I add them".

Comment: @Karl you are still missing the case were one number appears thrice and another twice (such as $43344$).  Complement is valid but in this case has many more options then the direct, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t want to be influenced by your solution so before looking at it, I independently determined how many 5-digit numbers would satisfy your conditions.

I came up with exactly the same three cases and my calculation of the number of 5-digit numbers in each case was the same as yours so I feel your answer is correct.

Since your three cases (0 pairs, 1 pair and 2 pairs) are mutually exclusive, you can simply add the counts of the three cases to get the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, but as such problems are susceptible to errors, as is evidenced in comments, here is a mechanical way using the product of two multinomial coefficients, which totally saves you the labor of thought

$\textbf{[Lay down Pattern] x [Permute Pattern]}$ which yields

$$\binom{5}{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}\binom{10}{5,5} + \binom{5}{2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}\binom{10}{1,3,6} + \binom{5}{2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}\binom{10}{2,1,7} = 91440$$

$\boxed{\textbf{Added}}$

Of course, as the multinomial coefficient $\dbinom{5}{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}\color{red} {\equiv} \dfrac{5!}{1!1!1!1!1!0!0!0!0!0!} = 5!$,

by using the permutation form of the multinomial coefficients, and removing factorials of $1$ and $0$, you can *shorten* the expression substantially as

$$5!\cdot\frac{10!}{5!5!} + \frac{5!}{2!}\frac{10!}{3!6!} + \frac{5!}{2!2!}\frac{10!}{2!7!}$$